# How to recognize the type of number contained in a string in C?

Tags: c++, c

I need to recognize the type of number contained in a string (integer or floating point). In detail, I need understand the smallest type where I can store the number. I wish that unsigned types are preferable for positive values. Maybe it's easier to explain with some examples:

```
"123" -> unsigned char

"-21" -> char

"257" -> unsigned short

"-271"-> short

...

"....."  long long

"1.2"    float

"....."  double

"a"      NaN / error
```

I'm considering using strtoul, strtol, strtod, I wonder if there is a function (something like is_char(), is_float (), ... or num_type ()) or something "smart" (math based?, ...) for easy recognition before I start coding.

Thanks.

Comment: `limits.h` provides definitions of `*_MIN` and `*_MAX` (ie. `INT_MIN`) for integral types, which might come in handy for choosing a suitable variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by testing the negative.  Then I would look for a decimal point (and exponent notation) to determine whether to use integers or not.

For integers, convert the number to the largest signed or unsigned value (int64, presumably), then convert back to string and test that the number comes out the same (otherwise it cannot be represented by an int).

At that point you can use either bitshifts or bitmasks to check the size requirements.  Effectively you want to take the absolute value (in the case of signed types) and check for zeros on the left.  I'll show the basic idea for unsigned...

```
unsigned long long val;
// ...

if( 0 != (val >> 32) )
    printf( "unsigned long long\n" );
else if( 0 != (val >> 48) ) 
    printf( "unsigned long\n" );
else if( 0 != (val >> 56) ) 
    printf( "unsigned short\n" );
else
    printf( "unsigned char\n" );
```

For floating point, you might want read in the value as a double and then test against FLT_MAX, DBL_MAX etc...

Comment: simple ... and nice :) I myself was thinking more in terms of regex's and stuff but this will do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You mention preferring lower sizes first, unsigned second.  But is there a consistent "pecking order" on your types?  I mean to say: is there some string `S1` which can technically be converted into type X or type Y and choose X, but some string `S2` which could also be converted into type X or type Y, yet choose Y?

C++ terminology-wise, you might want to be aware of ["lexical casting"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).  If you do have a pecking order of the types you are interested in, you could try them in order and keep catching [bad_lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.bad_lexical_cast) exceptions until one works... :-/  Or write your own equivalent.

But beyond that, the compiled nature of C++ is such that by the time you've gotten to runtime and have an input string, tricks like `auto` aren't available.  Moreover, auto does not follow your idea as it decides the type of "1" is `int`.

You've been pointed at `limits.h` if you want to tackle your own method.  But if you're interested in the idiomatic C++ for that, then check out an article I wrote on the subject:

http://hostilefork.com/2009/03/31/modern_cpp_or_modern_art/

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, the OP stated that they preferred `unsigned` for non-negative types and gave the example of `123` being treated as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @paddy Missed that note (or forgot it was there after going to look for links)...but the observation was more generally that there would probably be some total order on the conversion plan.  I'll ask about that property instead...